# How does the halting theorem interact with the recursion theorem?

Tags: computability, halting-problem

Recursion theorem (paraphrasing Sipser, Introduction to the Theory of Computation):

Let T be a program that computes a function t: N x N --> N. There is a program R that computes a function r: N --> N, where for every w,

```
        t(<R>, w) = r(w)
```

The proof is by construction. The program R thus constructed computes the same thing as program T with one input fixed at <R>. But what if the right side does not compute anything? In that event we can reason as follows:

```
T(<R>, w) halts  <-->  R(w) halts
```

and by modus tollens

```
T(<R>, w)  does not halt  <-->  R(w) does not halt
```

In particular we have

```
R(w) halts  --> T(<R>, w) halts
T(<R>, w)  does not halt  --> R(w) does not halt
```

The transposition is based on the table below

T(<R>, w) halts__________________R(w) halts

```
   T                         T
   F                         F
```

But what if the value in the right column is unknown and unknowable?

T(<R>, w) halts__________________R(w) halts

```
   T                         T
   ?                     unknowable 
   F                         F
```

We know that there is no universal halting decider, so the value in the right column may be unknowable to a given decider. So what if the decider concludes that T(<R>,w) does not halt? Is there anything wrong with the table below?

T(<R>, w) halts__________________R(w) halts

```
   T                         T
   F                     unknowable
   F                         F
```

In particular is there any compelling reason that if the value in the left column is F that the value in right column must also be F, i.e. that it cannot remain unknowable? It seems to me that if T(<R>, w) does not halt then it does not imply anything.

Is it possible for a decider to say [for some T] that T(<R>, w) does NOT halt yet remain agnostic about R(w) halting??

Answer (score 1):

The recursion theorem states that for every two-place *partially computable* function $t$ there is a program $R$ which computes a *partial function* $r$ satisfying
$$ r(w) = t(\langle R \rangle, w) $$
for all $w$. The function $t$ is given by a program that doesn't necessarily halt, and so we can think of it as a function from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \bot \}$, where $\bot$ means that the program doesn't halt. We call such a function a *partial function*, since a different way of specifying such a function is as a function from some *subset* $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}$; the function doesn't halt on inputs outside $S$.

The equality $r(w) = t(\langle R \rangle, w)$ is an equality of partial functions: the functions have the same domain (or the same set of inputs on which the output is a natural number rather than $\bot$), and they agree on their domain.